# How to display different styles on index posts in wordpress pages?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

I want to add a new div on wordpress index.php thumbnails. When hovered a new div should cover the thumbnail. The problem is that whatever I add to index.php it will affect all posts, so if a user hovers one thumbnail the effect will hit all posts thumbnails. Any ideas on how to fix it?

You can have a glimpse of what I am building at techgeek.lt/naudinga/

Answer (score 1):

Please see [Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) in Codex to determine which template would be fitting to precisely target what you want modified. You might need to create such template and add to theme.

Alternative would be to use [Conditional Tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) to control output of additional markup.